# How to fix the onepage anchors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i'm doing my portfolio and I have a problem during declaration of the differents anchors on my navbar.

I'm using bootstrap to do, but with my navbar it doesn't work

```
<nav id="colorlib-main-nav" role="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="js-colorlib-nav-toggle colorlib-nav-toggle active"><i></i></a>
      <div class="js-fullheight colorlib-table">
        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/IMG_2418.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="colorlib-table-cell js-fullheight">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <h1 class="mb-4"><a href="index.html" class="logo"></a></h1>
              <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span><small>01</small>Accueil</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#about"><span><small>02</small>À Propos</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#projets"><span><small>03</small>Projets</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html"><span><small>04</small>Portfolio</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html"><span><small>05</small>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><span><small>06</small>Contact</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

The result is, my navbar stay stuck on ' Accueil ' when I click on about of projets.

Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace all of this with.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid -->
```

And have put your changes in this.

Comment: Its might happen when files are not correctly loaded. Please check your links.

Comment: you have to replace all of that with the code provided above.